# users own iCloud account to store files for an iOS app

Tags: ios, icloud

In one of my app I have to let user load their own files for which I think iCloud is the proposed mechanism but it may create a memory and IP (intellectual property) issues. To address this, is it not possible if users can download their files in my app from their own iCloud accounts. 
As per my knowledge so far the iCloud access is limited by configuring it to an account at the time of build while performing entitlement.
Can someone please throw some ideas on this situation?

Comment: As not only a developer, but a user, don't you think it's a bit sketchy if you logged people into your iCloud account just to pull some files you could easily store on a server?  And besides, IP issues could get you into far worse trouble than you can ever imagine.  Make your own content, or get a fair license before you literally steal other people's ideas.

Comment: I don't think if you understood my query, I asked it exactly seeing these issues. It asks how to enable users to use their own iCloud accounts to store their precious documents and load them with this App.

Comment: Well then it sounds like you need to take a read through the [iCloud storage guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html), because what you describe is exactly what iCloud is...